# amazon emr pig: use parameter file

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-pig, amazon-emr

Is it possible to pass a parameter file to your pig job on amazon?
Pig commandline supports this, but I can't figure out if amazon also supports this.
The main idea is that I don't need to send tons of parameters through commandline to amazon but just upload the file and use the parameter file with all the values from their.

So a parameter file would look like this:
param_name=param_value.

pig -f script.pig -param_file parameters.log works but now I just need to find the amazon alternative :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

To use a parameter file run it on amazon like this:

```
--args "-param_file,s3://<LOCATION_PARAM_FILE>"
```